# How a mean and st. deviation can be calculated from an imported MS Excel table?

Tags: r

I imported an [MS Excel table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18ndi5Go7L1pSjaSTnZSLpywGLw3LhGDy/edit#gid=722574190) in R 4.2.1, using  the clipboard

```
library(clipr)

my_data <- read_clip_tbl()
my_data
```

```
   Year    Contract Compensation
1  2014    Oerlikon        95741
2  2014    Oerlikon       105771
3  2015    Oerlikon        90799
4  2015    Oerlikon        90282
5  2015    Oerlikon        89485
6  2016    Oerlikon       108976
7  2016    Oerlikon        84187
8  2016    Oerlikon       117542
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to use https://rdrr.io/snippets/ to interface with a file or clipboard.

When I try to calculate the mean or standard deviation on the compensation field, I get a message that the argument is not numeric

> mean (my_data,compensation)
> [1] NA
> Warning message:
> In mean.default(my_data, compensation) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Is there a way to import an MS Excel table to  https://rdrr.io/snippets/ ?
How can I get the right format (vectorize?) of the table?

The expected average is 100.185,82 and the St Dev is 19.951,74

Comment: Do you want `mean(my_data$compensation)`?

Comment: @Roland , yes. the mean value of the compensations should be 100185. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Roland's comment, you could also do, for standard deviation:

```
sd(as.numeric(my_data$compensation))
```

Comment: Hi Roland, Peixe and Zephryl. Yes, I need to have the standard deviation on the values of the list. Since it is not taken as a number, the result is returning NA. Thanks!

Comment: Then you might want to convert it to numeric, as the default behaviour for the `read_clip_tbl()` function can be to import data as characters. Do instead:
`sd(as.numeric(my_data$compensation))`

Comment: Many thanks, Peixe. It worked. The as.numeric function gets the job!